# Inter web application communication with ASP.NET MVC and CAS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest, cas

We have implemented several intranet web applications in my company. They all:

1. are built by ASP.NET MVC 3
2. use CAS(ticket in cookie policy) and a shared LADP server to single sign on
3. have role based access control logic according to current logon user
4. expose many RESTful(like) web apis for page's ajax usage

Now we find those web apis for ajax requests can be used as services for other web applications(like employee info, client info etc). Which means we need to access those apis at backend(with C# code). The problem is the authentication and authorization.

I don't know how to go with the existing authentication mode to access those web apis. I can only think of a way that use an shared service credential among back end servers but it means this credential must have a full access authority. Is it a security risk? And as I metioned, we use ticket in cookie policy with CAS. Which is OK for browser but seems difficult for C# code. How to use a credential with CAS from backend? Use a WebClient and handle 302 manually?

Has anyone met a similar case and have some good experiences with this? Please give me some advice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is to use the CAS proxy mode to access backend web services : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Proxy+CAS+Walkthrough.

Comment: Thanks @jlelue. After reading the wiki of CAS, I find the proxy is designed to solve my problem. I'll try to leverage it in my projects and see if it is suitable.